# How to use GStreamer in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

Do I have to compile **GStreamer** on my own? Can I do it using Visual Studio 2010?

I'm struggling to find a good step-by-step guide with instructions on how to do this. Is there a good one?

My objective is to build applications using **[QtGstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html)** on VS2010.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.gstreamer-winbuild.ylatuya.es/doku.php?id=developers

Comment: Nice reference. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Simon you should add your link as an answer, its good stuff.

Comment: @karlphillip: the answer is not alive anymore. Please post updates for 2015 now Visual studio is 2013 need Gstreamer 1.4.x

Comment: I wont. Gstreamer now offers binaries for Windows, there's no need to build it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This links gives a complete method to [compile GStreamer using Visual Studio](http://web.archive.org/web/20130324094628/http://www.gstreamer-winbuild.ylatuya.es/doku.php?id=developers) and this one is to [compile QtGstreamer](http://web.archive.org/web/20121218092627/http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/QtGStreamer/BuildingOnWindows).

Comment: URLs are dead. Hello??????????????????? Hello????????????????? Anyone know how Gstreamer 1.0 can be used in Visual studio 2013??????

Comment: Not dead but hopeless.  Paths are all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out build from OSSBuild. You should use svn client to checkout address

> http://ossbuild.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Shared/Build/Windows/Win32

Then it is only matter of configuring VS2010 to know where to look for it. It contains all thet one needs already compiled. Since i run linux i have no possibility of checking how to configure it correctly.

Comment: I've seen that project already but I haven't tried it due to the lack of time. Maybe someone is willing to assist me on that.

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to GStreamer in there :(

Answer (score 0):

- Download the GStreamer libraries and headers for windows.
- Put them in a folder.
- Add the folder's path to your Include Directories and Library Directories. (Project Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories)
- Add the library to your linker's list of libraries to link to (woah!).

Ok... that last one isn't so bad: Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependancies (add the name of the library e.g. gstreamer.lib or gstreamer.dll)

- #include < gstreamer.h > (or whatever the header you need to include is called)
- if your using QtGstreamer, ignore the previous step and #include < QtGstreamer.h >

Note: you may have to do the same setup for the QtGstreamer libraries and headers as the one for Gstreamer, and yes, QtGstreamer relies on Gstreamer so you need to setup for both.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Can you provide links for the packages you are suggesting me to download?

Comment: if we are talking abt this "ossbuild-build-env.exe" then it can be downlowd here http://ossbuild.hoytsoft.org/downloads/downloads.aspx

Comment: `Download the GStreamer libraries and headers for windows.` From where?!?!?

Comment: Not working i have done Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependancies (add the name of the library e.g. gstreamer.lib or gstreamer.dll) but still it says gstreamer.h or gst/gst.h no such file or directory.

Comment: This is a general procedure. Can you provide anything specific to GStreamer?