# GStreamer C++ on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gstreamer, glib

Following instructions on http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows to install GStreamer and compile tutorials/examples on Windows 7, for compilation using Visual Studio 2010.

After installing the SDKs, I try to compile the "hello world" example...

```
Cannot open include file: 'gst/gst.h': No such file or directory.
```

Odd - the tutorials were supposedly configured with the paths to these files.  Nevertheless, we can manually add them...

Add C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86\include\gstreamer-0.10 to project include directories

```
Cannot open include file: 'glib.h': No such file or directory
```

Add C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86\include\glib-2.0 to project include directories

```
Cannot open include file: 'glibconfig.h': No such file or directory
```

At this point it seems to be a dead-end, as there isn't a glibconfig.h file anywhere on PC.

Was some step missing from the gstreamer documents?

p.s. I see [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334811/how-to-use-gstreamer-in-visual-studio-2010), but its accepted answer seems to be a dead-link.

Answer (score 13):

This question was posted on 2014. However, for everyone that needs to install Gstreamer on Visual Studio , I am explaining how you configure your library on Windows.

First of you need to download the library from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/

You need to download and install both installers for developers and non-developers.

For instance for 1.14 it is the now latest version,

- **gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86-1.14.1.msi**
- **gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.14.1.msi**

You will install and setup both of them in the same directory like `C:\gstreamer`. (I guess gstreamer automatically adds its `/bin` to the Path environment. If not just ask it.)

After that you will open your Visual Studio. Create your C++ project. Create your `main.cpp` file. Right click on your project and click properties.

We need to do 3 steps:

1. Include the necessary directory paths.
2. Define the where the `.lib` paths are.
3. Specify which `.libs` you want to use.

After clicking properties:

1. C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories -> define your include paths such as

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0\include;C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0;C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\glib-2.0\;C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\glib-2.0\glib;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

2. Linker -> General -> Adding Library Directories -> write your lib directory path such as

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

3. Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> Write your .lib files you want to use such as

```
gobject-2.0.lib;glib-2.0.lib;gstreamer-1.0.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

`gobject-2.0.lib;glib-2.0.lib;gstreamer-1.0.lib` are the ones we added, others are done by default.

That's all. You can just write in your `main.cpp` file

`#include <gst/gst.h>` and use your GStreamer Library

I think this will work for almost all libraries.

Comment: Confirmed this works with MSVC 2019 and gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-1.20.2

Answer (score 3):

(1) Install Windows Driver Development Kit

(2) When creating new projects, use the "gstreamer" template in Visual Studio, rather than the "Windows application" template.  Then it doesn't need anything changing in the include/linker settings to make `#include <gst/gst.h>` work properly.

Comment: Could you explain how Windows Driver Development Kit helps? Also, is there a way to change a project's template after the fact? This guy's bug (and mine) is with the existing gstreamer tutorial projects.

Answer (score 1):

The standard gstreamer installation on windows has a glibconfig.h located in: (assuming your gstreamer installation is in C:\gstreamer) `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0\include`

Answer (score 1):

The official way is using the "Property Sheet" feature of Visual Studio.

1. In Visual Studio, click `View→Property Manager` or `View→Other Windows→Property Manager` on the menu bar.
2. Click `Property Manager` tab near the `Solution Explorer`.
3. Right click your project name and choose `Add Existing Property Sheet...`, and navigate to `%GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86%\share\vs\2010\libs` and load `gstreamer-1.0.props`.
4. This will add `Addittional Include Directories, Addittional Libraries Directories and Additional Dependencies` to your `Project Properties`.
5. Build your project.

**Sources:**

Creating new projects manually:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html?gi-language=c#creating-new-projects-manually

Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations